# Perl How to find positions of captures

Tags: regex, perl

I have a space-seperated file like this:

```
 First        Second        Third       Forth
 It               is        possible    to   
 do             this                    task
 with          regex        but         i
 don't          know        how         to
```

My task is to capture all the words of each line and construct a hash from them.

But here is my problem: Fields may be empty in any column (e.g. 3rd line, 3rd field).

Words in each line are aligned by the column's name at their beginning or end. (column's names are the words in the first line , e.g. `First Second Third Forth`)

In my example, words are aligned to left (or to beginning of column name) in `First Third Forth` columns and are aligned to right (or to end of column name) in `Second`

Using the hash from each line I have to create output formatted like this:

`$hash{First} has Second-property $hash{Second}. It also has $hash{Third} and $hash{Forth}.`

```
use File::Basename;
use locale;
open my $file, "<", $ARGV[0];
open my $file2,">>",fileparse($ARGV[0])."2.txt";
my @alls = <$file>;

sub Main{
my $first = shift @alls;
my $poses = First_And_Last($first);
my $curr_poses;
my $curr_hash;
#do{OutputLine($_->[0],$_->[1],$first)}for (@$poses);
my $result_array=[];
my @keys = qw(# Variable Type Len Format Informat Label);
for $word(@alls){
    $curr_poses=First_And_Last($word);
    undef ($curr_hash);
    $curr_hash = Take_Words($poses, $word, $curr_poses);
    push @{$result_array},$curr_hash; #AoH  
    }

#end of main
}

sub First_And_Last{
    #First_And_Last($str)
    my $str = shift;    
    my $begin;
    my $end;
    my $ref=[];
    while ($str=~m/(([\S\.]\s?)+\b|#)/g){       
        $begin = pos($str) - length($1);
        $end = pos($str);       
        push @{$ref},[$begin,$end];
        }               
    return $ref;
    }

sub Take_Words{
    #Take_Words($poses, $line,$current) 
    my $outref = {};
    my $ref = shift; #take the ref of offsets of words
    my $line = shift;# and the next line in file
    my $current = shift; # and this is the poses of current line
    my @keys = qw(# Variable Type Len Format Informat Label);
    do{$outref->{$_}=undef;}for(@keys);
    my $ethalon; #for $ref
    my $relativity; #for $current
    my $key; #for key in $outref
    my @ethalon = @{$ref};

    $ethalon = shift @ethalon;
    $relativity = shift @{$current};
    $key = shift @keys;

    while (defined($key) && defined($relativity)){
        if ($ethalon->[0] == $relativity->[0] || $ethalon->[1] == $relativity->[1]){    
                $outref->{$key} = substr($line, $relativity->[0],$relativity->[1] - $relativity->[0]);          

                $relativity = shift @{$current};
            }
            $ethalon = shift @ethalon;
            $key = shift @keys;         
        }


    return $outref;
    }
```

Comment: are the fields fixed-width or does the width of each column has to be determined at run-time? Both is possible...

Comment: Did not understand a thing...

Comment: @amon not, not fixed-width. it defined, when table created like this: in each column was determined maximum of word's length.

Comment: is there a maximum of one word per field, or may there be multiple words seperated by a space character in each field?

Comment: @amon good question. in fact, there can be a string (not only one word). but in string words separated by one space.

Comment: Is it really not possible to change the format of the input? Only left-aligned columns? Multiple-word-strings enclosed by quotes? Parsing the above is not impossible, just somewhat difficult.

Comment: @m0skit0 what you can't understand? it is table in text, where first line contains names of columns. every word in column is aligned to the beginning of the name of column or to the end of name of column

Comment: @amon not, it is not possible. here i can give you my code

Comment: Hmmm. Is it possible that a field is so long it reaches under the heading of another column?

Comment: @amon not, it isn't possible. minimum 2 spaces between end of previos and beginning of next column

Comment: You can only do this with a regex if you know the width of the columns beforehand (and then you don't need to use a regex any more).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my algorithm, but it is somewhat C-ish:

1. Determine the starting position of each column heading and store it.
2. For each column: Go to the headings starting position.
3. step left until you have passed two consecutive spaces.
4. go right two characters, then remember the position.
5. go right until you have passed two consecutive spaces.
6. go left two characters, then remeber the position.
7. Extract everything between the found boundaries.
8. remove starting and trailing white spaces.
9. Store in your hash
10. repeat from step 2

Now we'll have to see about that implementation:

Step 1:

```
my @starting;
{
  my @char = split m{}, <$file>; # split the first line into char array
  my $spacecount = 0;
  my $state = 1; # 1 : find start -- 0 : find end
  for (my $i = 0; $i < @char; $i++) {
    if ($state) { # find next non-space
      if ($char[$i] =~ /\s/) {
        next;
      } else {
        $state = not $state; # flip
        $spacecount = 0;
        push @starting, $i;
        next;
      }
    } else {
      if ($char[$i] =~ /\s/) {
        $spacecount++;
        if ($spacecount >= 2) {
          $state = not $state; # flip
          next;
        }
      } else {
        $spacecount = 0; # reset consecutive space counter
        next;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @loldop, please drop me a comment if this does or doesn't work, I am quite curious myself.